# Video capture code using ipwebcam does not work in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using ipwebcam to use my phone camera as web cam and the code works fine on python IDE but the same code does not work in Google colab.
The ipwebcam gives a line feed from my phone camera in a specified url.

This is the code:

```
import requests
import cv2
import numpy as np
url="https://192.164.45.1342:8080/shot.jpg"
while True:
  img_resp=requests.get(url)
  img_arr=np.array(bytearray(img_resp.content), dtype=np.uint8)
  img=cv2.imdecode(img_arr,-1)
  cv2.imshow("image",img)
  if cv2.waitKey(1)==27:
      break
```

This code is used to get frame by frame from the above mentined url, which is live feed from my mobile phone and display it as a video.
In google colab I am not getting any output

This is the error:

TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.43.149', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /shot.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.43.149', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /shot.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

Answer (score 0):

Colab code executes on a backend that is not connected to your local network. So, the address `192.164.45.1342` won't be reachable from a Colab backend.

A potential work-around is to use a [local Jupyter runtime](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html). Or, you could save images locally and then transfer them to Colab.